# How do I disable auto triggers of jedi autocompletion on certain characters in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, jedi-vim

The jedi pop up doesn't get triggered on space ' '. But it get triggered on '=' which is useless and distracting and autocomplete dialog covers the screen. How can I stop it from getting triggered on '=' ?

I use zchee/deoplete-jedi and Shougo/deoplete.nvim.

The autocomplete box is automatically triggered which typing no special command is needed (just like in YoucompleteMe)

Screenshot of the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCrbb.jpg

Comment: Use plugins issue tracker

Comment: This has nothing to do with jedi-vim or jedi. It's probably a deoplete issue.

Comment: Ok, the reason I added jedi is because the only suggestions visible after typing '='s is jedi suggestions. Of course it could still be a deoplete issue.